# Django: Query that filters data from 2 models that have ForeignKey relation with my Vehicle model

Tags: django, orm, django-views

I am trying to write a query that returns `Vehicle` objects. The query should  filter by a particular `Garage` object (i.e., garage__name = ) and by a particular `Category` object (i.e., category__name = ), and where the `Vehicle` object's **available** field is **True** (available = True). These are the models:

```
class Garage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length = 30, blank=False)
    zip = models.IntegerField (blank=False)
    area = models.CharField (max_length = 30, blank=False)
    pic = models.ImageField (upload_to ='static/images/garages')

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    car_no = models.CharField (max_length = 20, blank=False)
    photo = models.ImageField (upload_to ='static/images/vehicles')
    car_model = models.ForeignKey (Car_model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    garage = models.ForeignKey (Garage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey (Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length = 15, blank=False)
```

What I've tried in the corresponding view function is this:

```
def carSelectView(request, type, grg):
    cars=Vehicle.objects.filter(category__name=type, garage__name=grg, available=True)
    return render(request, 'carphotoselectpage.html', {'ca':cars})
```

But it's returning an empty page. Before this approach, i tried to get the cars of a particular category only and it worked:

```
def carSelectView(request, type):
    cars = Vehicle.objects.filter(category__name = type).filter(available=True)
```

I can't understand where the problem lies. I want to show vehicles by 1. selecting a particular `Garage`, and then 2. selecting the vehicles from that `Garage` that matches the `Category` name. 3. Whose **available** field is **True**.

Is the `Vehicle` model not fetching the `Garage` model in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, so this is likely a problem with what's being passed in the `type` and `grg` variables rather than a problem with your query.

To debug, try the following:

- Use `print()` commands to output the values stored within the `type` and `grg` variables to your terminal. Check to ensure that they are as expected.
- User `$ python manage.py shell` to boot up your terminal, then manually run your query to ensure that it returns the expected output. `from .models import Vehicle`, then `Vehicle.objects.filter(category__name='REAL CATEGORY', garage__name='REAL GARAGE', available=True)`. Ensure that you get results back. if you don't, try removing criteria one by one until you can isolate the source of the problem.
- Ensure that your template properly displays `Car` instances when provided with them. Try passing it an instance of a `Car` that you know exists (e.g., `Car.objects.all()`) and make sure that it is displaying proper output.

Comment: The problem was with the __str__(): methods of the model classes. The 'type' and 'grg' arguments were passing the whole gibberish i had written to output in the __str__() method. I edited the method to return just the name attribute and it worked.